# Regex javascript to match href

Tags: javascript, regex

Logout

That above is what I want to search for.

I want to get h= and t= from that URL, or just get the entire url in href=""

How would I do this with regex?

Comment: parse it with an HTML parser, parsing HTML with regex will always in end in tears eventually.

Comment: Will your search strings always follow that same format (<u class="..." href="...)?

Comment: Yes, it will always follow the same format.

Comment: In the spirit of @fuzzy's comment, I refer you to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Do you know how I would do this? That's fine if it ends in tears :x

Comment: @zx, "YOURHTMLTEXT".match(/href="[^"]+"/g)

Comment: that is actually valid XML using an XML parser would be a better idea than a REGEX, learn from what people are saying and don't do it the wrong way. Use a real parser.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to get the `href` with:

```
var array_of_matches = str.match(/href="([^"]*")/g)
```

Look for 'href="' then start a capture group of all non-double-quote characters, until it ends with a final doublequote.  You can pull out the query arguments using more groups inside that group.

Look at this [javascript regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).  And the global flag to get the array of matches described in the [string regex api](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev3.shtml).

Comment: Yeah, that just gets the first url on the page. There are multiple href links

Comment: It is valid to keep in mind that this solution will ignore hrefs found between single quotes. To work around that, I would suggest the following: http://regexr.com/3f7q4

Answer (score 1):

This should return both `h` and `t` values:

```
logout.php\?h=(\w+)&t=(\w+)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/href="[^"]+"/g
```

Comment: @zx, `"YOURHTMLTEXT".match(/href="[^"]+"/g)`