# Remove contents of href attribute with with RegEx

Tags: php, regex

For example, I have this HTML snippet:

```
<a href="/sites/all/themes/code.php">some text</a>
```

The question is - how to cut the text `/sites/all/themes/code.php` from the `href` with `preg_replace()`; which pattern could I use?

Comment: Possible Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792900/regex-javascript-to-match-href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pattern:

```
(<a .*?href=")([^"]*)
```

replacement: $1

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend against using regular expressions to parse any [SGML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language) derivative.

For HTML use some DOM parser. For PHP specifically there is [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to do a "replace"

```
(?<=<a href=")[^"]*(?=">)
```

brings you what you want directly.

test with grep:

```
kent$  echo '<a href="/sites/all/themes/code.php">some text</a>'|grep -oP '(?<=<a href=")[^"]*(?=">)'                                    
/sites/all/themes/code.php
```